# Airflow with KubernetesExecutor workers (EKS) and webserver+scheduler on EC2

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I wanted to know if it's possible to setup a KubernetesExecutor on Airflow but having the webserver and scheduler running on an EC2?

Meaning that tasks would run on Kubernetes pods (EKS in my case) but the base services on a regular EC2.

I tried to find information about the issue but failed short...

the following quote is from Airflow's [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html), and it's the reason I'm asking this question

```
KubernetesExecutor runs as a process in the Airflow Scheduler. The scheduler itself does not necessarily need to be running on Kubernetes, but does need access to a Kubernetes cluster.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible.

You just need to run your `airflow scheduler` and `airflow webserver` on EC2 and configure the EC2 instance to have all the necessary acces (via service account likely - but this is your decision and deployment configuration) to be able to spin pods on your EKS cluster.

Nothing special about it besides that you will have to learn how to run and configure the components to talk to each other - there are no ready-to-use recipes, you will have to simply follow theconfiguration parameters of Airflo, and authentication schemes that you need to have.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! Do you any idea what airflow setting will I need to set for this implementation? Like I said, I haven't been able to find any information about this.

Comment: There is no "setting"  - you need to configure your deployment following the architecture here : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/overview.html - but sunce you want custom setting and not Helm Chart for example  - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html (which install everything in Kubernetes) you need ot make sure you run all the components (few applications), database, authentication in the way you usually deploy other apps in similar deployments. But there is no "setting" - you just need to setup the whole deploment yourself.

Comment: It's about a couple of days of work for experience devops (or even devops team) to set-up , so I guess you do not expect this will be explained in a commen :)?

Comment: I meant settings as airflow.cfg settings.
I assume AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__CONFIG_FILE should be the path to the cluster config file. But, should AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__IN_CLUSTER be true or false? it's not very clear from the docs

Comment: `Path to the kubernetes configfile to be used when in_cluster is set to False` - isn't that clear enough ? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#config-file